# How to make global pages as using defferent URI

Tags: php, symfony

Currently I have a page like this

http://mypage.com/

I put every languages in the same page and languages are judged by user locale setting.

However, I have heard its not good for SEO.

I would like to use defferent URL like

http://mypage.com/fr

http://mypage.com/en

http://mypage.com/ja

I have many questions.
where should I judge the language??
How I redirect page to page ??
How do I write routing.yml??

```
acme_top_top:
    pattern:  /fr
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Default:index }
acme_top_top:
    pattern:  /en
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Default:index }
```

I have googled many times but cant find the guideline document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using the _locale of the [Routing component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) as follow:

```
# app/config/routing.yml

acme_top_top:
    path:      /{_locale}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Default:index, _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale:  en|fr
```

You can define a default locale also. More info on the doc page.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks you hit my problem!!

Comment: and now I use this bundle http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration . it's also great help